# Compiling gcc with debug flags

Tags: debugging, gcc, makefile, configure, libstdc++

I am trying to build gcc version 10.00.1 from source with debugging flags to enable some functions such as methods from the STL to be able to print in GDB. Right now GDB will say things such as "cannot find method std::stringstream::str" even when I have the `-g3` flag on when compiling my program.

The documentation of gcc says to configure the application using the `--enable-libstdcxx-debug` flag to be able to enable this support. I decided to build the application with the same flags my distro configured gcc with which are

`-v --with-pkgversion='Debian 9.2.1-28' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-mutex`

after a successful `make` and `make install` I still have the same problem with GDB not finding the methods. I decided to build libstdc++ by itself with just the `--enable-libstdc++-debug` flag. But I cannot find where the libstdc++.so.6 file anywhere in the build. I have not ran a `make install` yet either as I do not want to break my system. Where should the libstdc++.so.6 be located in the build? Thanks

Comment: Just adding `-g` flag worked for me. See more debug options here:https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html

Answer (score 0):

> I have not ran a `make install` yet either as I do not want to break my system.

Use `--prefix` option to `configure` to specify an alternative install location to avoid replacing your system `gcc`.

> I decided to build `libstdc++` by itself with just the `--enable-libstdc++-debug` flag.

Make sure you `make clean` after re-`configure`, so that `make` rebuilds it with the new compiler and linker flags.